# How to aggregate one index of an array field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have documents that look like this:

```
{  
    "clientId": "FPIev_86RwB",
    "viewId": "FPIewF1aRyU",
    "sessionId": "FPIewE16Rxu",
    "trackingId": "FPIewHfaRx9",
    "type": "view",
    "intVal": [  
        21,
        72,
        37
    ]
}
```

I want to different aggregations (such as sum or avg) on just one index of the array across a set of documents. However, it seems that I can't specify the index like I could specify a field on an object. Here is what I tried:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "avg_1": {
            "avg": {
                "field": "intVal.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I tried selecting the index of the field with `intVal.1` but that isn't working. I have a variable number of values that may be added to an array, but the values in a specific index position are all for the same thing so I want to do an aggregation on the array index. Is there any way I can make this work?

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution using a script. The query looks like this:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "avg_1": {
            "avg": {
                "script": "doc['intVal'][1].value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```